# Configure converting value of string to zero in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm receiving from sensor Listener(Inside the android device) the values of step I just walked before. I'm trying to make it more useful for users when they lunch their apps. 
It was counting some numbers like 2213 (my previous steps). So I wrote down below a code to let it starts counting from 0 each time onChange method gets call. 
But it looks to me it didn't works and  the app is just crashed. it complaining about count.setText(ii);
I'm still beginner. so Could please help me understand what is going on.

```
  int  Initials;
String  Finals ;
int ii=0;
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activityRunning){
        Initials = Integer.valueOf((int) event.values[0]);

        ii =Initials;
        Finals = String.valueOf(ii);
        count.setText(ii);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem at this line

```
count.setText(ii);
```

Please change to

```
count.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
```

Because `ii` is int value, so it will looking for a resource id with value `ii`: `public final void setText (int resid)`

**EDIT**

If this problem still exists after you use `count.setText(Finals);` please check your `count` variable. Did you initial `count`

*Please correct coding convention when using Java*